# The definition of Fourier Integral seems wrong in my textbook.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The definition of Fourier Integral seems wrong in my textbook.
The definition in book goes like this,

If $f(x)$ is continuous and $\int_{-l}^{l}\left | f(x) \right |dx$ converges to zero as $l$ approaches to infinity, then $f(x)$ can be represented by $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left [ A(\omega)\cos\, \omega x + B(\omega) \sin\, \omega x\right ]d\omega$$
where, $$A(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \cos (\omega x )\, dx$$
$$B(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \sin (\omega x) \, dx$$

I can't understand one thing how can $\int_{-l}^{l}\left | f(x) \right |dx$ converge to zero when $l$ approaches $\infty$. Is't it only possible if $f(x)=0$ otherwise any function say, $f(x)$ have some part above or below X-axis and $\left | f(x) \right |$ integrated over an range > 0.

I asked my professor about it but I didn't get what he said can somebody explain ?

Comment: Is the integration range over your Fourier integral correct? Based on your $A(\omega),B(\omega)$ I'd have expected $f(x)$ to also be an integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$ rather than just $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: I think there is a  typo. The author meant to say $\int_{|x|>l}|f(x)|dx \to 0$.

Comment: Your professor is mistaken if he said that $\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\int_{|x|\le \ell}|f(x)|\,dx=0$ is a meaningful, non-trivial condition.  As you correctly asserted, if $f\in C$ and if  $\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\int_{|x|\le \ell}|f(x)|\,dx=0$, then $f\equiv 0$.  And if $f\equiv 0$, then the conclusion is trivial since $A=B=0$ follows.  That is, $0=0$.  Wow.

Comment: @Semiclassical it is correct Sir, It basically came from a term + discrete sum from n = 1 to infinity. Incorrect part is the integral I pointed out. I know, I said where did it come from very vaguely but basically the integral is correct.